# how load paused scene again in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have 3 scenes first is main game scene. When I pause that scene I replace it with other scene and then other view is loaded i.e. main menu so when I click on continue button on that scene I have to resume main game scene but it shows 2nd scene with which I have replaced the game scene. I don't know what to do because I have used both views and scenes in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really clear to me.. and by the fact it hasn't been answered previously, I suppose its not clear to others either.

Can you possibly post the code (abbreviated if its long) which you use to replace the scene and the view?

Do I understand it correct that you use:

- a scene for main game (first scene)
- a scene with a view in it for the menu (second scene)

When you pause the game, the first scene is replaced by the second scene. But when you press continue, the second scene (menu) isn't replaced by the first one (main game)?

Comment: yes u got it right. I have solved this problem by using push scene instead of replacing scene. so when i press continue the button I pop the scene and resume it. Now it works fine. any ways thanks nash8114.